# Cannot read filenames that are in utf8 encoding (Greek characters)

Tags: 12.10, encoding, filename

I've downloaded some files using "Download as .zip" option provided by Dropbox.
The filenames contain Greek characters.
I've extracted them and all I get is this: `2013 Î§ÎµÎ¹Î¼ÎµÏÎ¹Î½Ï.pdf`
The files were probably named/created on Windows OS, with greek locale.

I've looked into it and installed `convmv` utility but when using this command:
**1st attempt:**
`convmv -t utf8 ./2013 Î§ÎµÎ¹Î¼ÎµÏÎ¹Î½Ï.pdf`, I got this output:

> Your Perl version has fleas #37757 #49830
>    Starting a dry run without
>   changes...
>    Skipping, already UTF-8: ./2013 Î§ÎµÎ¹Î¼ÎµÏÎ¹Î½Ï.pdf
>   No changes to your files done. Use --notest to finally rename the files.

So, the filenames are already in utf8 but arent't properly displayed.
**2nd attempt:**
Searched for greek encodings and found these two `ISO 8859-7` and `windows-1253`.
Tried with the 1st one and got that `iso-8859-7 doesn't cover all needed characters for: "./2013 Î§ÎµÎ¹Î¼ÎµÏÎ¹Î½Ï.pdf"`. 
So no luck with this as well.

I then used `convmv --list` and `windows-1253` didn't appear.

So I am out of ideas, is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: This would be easier if we had a file to play with, could you give us a link to one of them? Anyway, see my answer to a similar question [here](http://superuser.com/a/604479/151431), does that help?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because default Ubuntu archive manager file-roller uses p7zip to unzip zip archives, if p7zip-full is installed. P7zip-full does not treat non-English file names correctly.

I made a PPA with file-roller using unzip program instead of p7zip.
Patched file-roller can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/file-roller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install file-roller
```

I maintain versions for LTS only. The patch is available at Launchpad and can be easily applied to non-LTS versions.

Comment: six years later...and this is still the case. Thank you.

Comment: however, unzip also showes incorrect names (they seem cyrillic)

Comment: It works for me. Maybe `file-roller` got an update and you have a wrong version. Check which one is installed.

Comment: I am on Kubuntu, so it uses Ark. The file was created on windows 10, by a client (I do not know with what software). I actually used unzip on the terminal, which gives cyrillic names, 7zip on the terminal destroys the info (gives squares), while ARK does also gives other wrong encoding...Peazip gives questionmarks...

Comment: thanks, use your `file-roller` with `UNZIP='-O CP936' ZIPINFO='-O CP936' bin/file-roller` solved my trouble

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and `p7zip` caused the problem.

Just using unzip command `unzip download.zip` did the job for me.