# Japanese file names break

Tags: files, encoding, japanese

I am trying to fix an encoding issue with any zip files or rar files that I unzip.

Anything I try to unzip through file-roller comes out like this

[image]

if using the unzip utility in terminal this is the output

```
  Archive:  romeo_inst.zip
  inflating: romeo/???~?I???V???f????.txt  
  inflating: romeo/???~?I???V???f????karaoke.mp3
```

I do not understand what is going wrong and I have tried everything including `convmv` and everything else!

Comment: @andrew.46 Thanks man! not used to this type of forums.

Answer (score 3):

```
 unzip -O cp932 filename.zip
```

Option `-O cp932` avoid this collapse, I think.

Comment: To add some reference, `-O` is for charsets of files generated from "_DOS, Windows and OS/2 archives_". If the file was created on Unix, use `-I`. And then, `cp932` refers to [Microsoft's Japanese encodings](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/encodings.html#encodings-CP932).

Answer (score 0):

I use this to unzip my japanese encoded zip files:

```
unzip -O shift-jis filename.zip
```

file-roller uses p7zip if you have it installed. I don't know how it handles it without p7zip, but the above command should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

### for GUI user: Archive Manager (file-roller)

A modified file-roller
https://askubuntu.com/a/611943/413480
[https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/file-roller](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/file-roller)

install the modified verfion file-roller (or just extract the file-roller in *.deb)

and run with

```sh
UNZIP='-O CP932' ZIPINFO='-O CP932' bin/file-roller
```

file names maybe right.